# CSS transition Chrome Issue

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have added `image-effect` class using jQuery `addClass` method and its CSS is as:

```
.image-effect img
{
  height:350px;
  transition: height 2s;
  -moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: height 2s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   }
```

jquery is as

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var jq = $.noConflict();
     jq(document).ready(function(){
     jq(".package-images").mouseover(function(){
     jq(this).addClass("image-effect");
     jq(".package-images").mouseout(function(){
     jq(this).removeClass("image-effect");
     });
    });
   });
   </script>
```

Height of the image is increased smoothly on all the browsers but not on chrome.

Why?

Comment: Maybe changing `1s` to `2s`?

Comment: Yes, When I keep it as 1s. It becomes fast. The clients are not satisfied by this.

Comment: Always use `transition: height 2s;` (without prefix) as the last one. So it will use that one instead of the prefixed versions if it can. I will try to find the source where I read this, but that was a long time ago. They had a good reason ;)

Comment: can you give me jsfiddle.?

Comment: Have updated this question

Comment: Add this CSS of `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your class name `.image-effect img` and if that works for you I write up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, don't use jquery. for do it use pseudo class :hover

```
<div class="package-images">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

css like this:

```
.package-images img{
  height:200px;
  transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
}
.package-images img:hover{
  height:350px;
}​
```

anyway, if you need to add a class name, your javascript code could be rewritten:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq(".package-images").mouseover(function(){
        jq(this).addClass("image-effect");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        jq(this).removeClass("image-effect");
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UZJdM/3/